# Facebook API & OAUTH - Request Permission before displaying app

Tags: facebook, request

I have a facebook app installed and working great. 
What I would like to do is add in the functionality of requesting user permission data. 
such as - read_friendlists,user_groups,email,user_birthday,status_update,publish_stream,

Firstly here is the code that checks if a fan or none fan is on our facebook timeline app.

```
// If a fan is on your page
if ($like_status) {
$a = file_get_contents("http://www.domain.com/home.php");
echo ($a);
} 
else {
// If a non-fan is on your page
$a = file_get_contents("http://www.domain.com/home.php");
echo ($a);
}
```

What I would like to do, is, if a none fan is on our page, open a facebook request for permission and set a number of permissions. Then redirect them to the // if a fan is on our page.

I have had a good look around here but I am still not clear how to setup the "request" for permission page.
Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Can you add some more information about your app? Is it a page tab app, or a canvas app, or are users landing on your site from facebook?

Comment: Users are landing on the timeline page inside of facebook.

Comment: @Connor Treacy Users are landing on the timeline page tab app inside of facebook. I am unable to add the full code as there are not enough characters available to me !

Comment: The app is working and I can direct them to a different page using the // if a none fan is on your page. What I am looking for is how to configure the facebook request for permission diag box.

Answer (score 2):

you can do this in two ways..

1) Open oauth dialog in page by setting the url

```
var oauth_url = 'https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth/';
oauth_url += '?scope=email,user_birthday,user_location,user_about_me,user_likes';
oauth_url += '&client_id=' + appid;
oauth_url += '&redirect_uri=' + encodeURIComponent('https://www.facebook.com/pages/' +   appname + '/' + pageId + '/?sk=app_' + appid);

window.top.location = oauth_url;
```

2) Or you can open the oauth dialog in popup:

```
FB.login(function(loginResponse) {
    if (loginResponse.authResponse) {
        var userId = loginResponse.authResponse.userID;
    }
    else {
        //'User cancelled login or did not fully authorize.
    }
}, { scope: 'email,user_birthday,user_location' });
```

Comment: many thanks for your reply, I will give this ago. 
Does this also include the option if a user clicks cancel on the OAUth request ?

Comment: Yes in first option you will be taken back to last page, in 2nd option in else block you can handle where to redirect the user.