# Auth dialog in a modal iframe

Tags: facebook, iframe, authentication, popup, modal-dialog

**Is there anyway to serve the login/auth dialog that results from a FB.login(…) call, in a custom iframe, i.e. not in the default popup?**

I've tried changing the *display* type to 'page' and sourcing it in an iframe, but it appears Facebook somehow blocks it. I understand why they would, but if possible I'd like to put the ugly popup in a lighbox-like modal iframe. If anyone has any success getting the login/auth dialog in something other than a popup, please let me know. Thanks!

Comment: You can open it in a separate page by redirecting to the url, take a look at it [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10381751/facebook-api-oauth-request-permission-before-displaying-app/10719689#10719689)

Comment: Thanks. I already use FB.login(…), which creates a popup. I don't want to change the current page to the login request, I want to modally display what is in the popup on the same page the user is already looking at.